# How does not the communion of the Saints invalidate the need for the bodily ressurection?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, saint, communion-of-saints, theology

Since the saints are said to be in the grave, if someone has answered that their spirits are in communion with Christ and interceding, then there would be no importance of the resurrection of bodies. Wouldn't this invalidate the need for the bodily resurrection?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  I'm sorry your first question has been down-voted with no explanation as to why.  Perhaps you could improve on your question by following the guide lines in our tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I don't think we're qualified to judge whether a bodily resurrection is or is not necessary. Not our decision.

Comment: I see your question has been edited but I am now totally confused.  Do you mean to ask if the Communion of the Saints DOESN'T invalidate the need for the bodily resurrection, or are you asking if the Communion of the Saints DOES invalidate the need for the bodily resurrection.  "How does not" is utterly confusing and I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnosticism and some other ancient heresies asserted that all matter was evil and spirit good. If God does not resurrect the dead, he is tacitly agreeing. To prove that a being consisting of matter and spirit can be wholly good, God must raise the dead.